# How can I get all column names from a table from a specific database in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

This query gives all the column names from all the databases.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers'
```

But I need to get all the column names from a table from a specific database. Because I have multiple tables with the same name. How to do that? Is there anything like

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATABASE_NAME = 'database_name' TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

I am using xampp server and phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Quote [the fine manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html):

> 26.3.8 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table
>
> ...
>
> The COLUMNS table has these columns:
>
> ```
> TABLE_CATALOG
>
> The name of the catalog to which the table containing the column belongs. This value is always def.
>
> TABLE_SCHEMA
>
> The name of the schema (database) to which the table containing the column belongs.
> ```
>
> ...

..you should see it when you do `SELECT *` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the SQL for my expected result

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this.

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'whatever'
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

The MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA uses columns named `TABLE_SCHEMA` to hold the database for each table.

Comment: Should I pass the database name inside the DATABASE() function? Without passing anything inside DATABASE() and putting the table name in place of 'whatever' shows me zero records. Even putting the database name inside the DATABASE() function gives me zero records.